# Вывести пользовательское поле пользователя типа список. Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет! Подскажите пожалуйста как вывести пользовательское поле пользователя типа список с возможностью выбора, то есть select методом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного помучившись нашел способ:

```html
<select name="UF_VDOC_USER">
  <option value="0" <?=$arResult[ "arUser"][ "UF_VDOC_USER"]=="0" ? " SELECTED=\"SELECTED\ "" : "Нет"?>>Выберите вид документа</option>
  <option value="13" <?=$arResult[ "arUser"][ "UF_VDOC_USER"]=="13" ? " SELECTED=\"SELECTED\ "" : "Паспорт"?>>Паспорт</option>
  <option value="14" <?=$arResult[ "arUser"][ "UF_VDOC_USER"]=="14" ? " SELECTED=\"SELECTED\ "" : "Водительское удостоверение"?>>Водительское удостоверение</option>
</select>
```

Пояснения:
name "код пользовательского свойства"
value "XML_ID"